# Confusion about Continuous Growth being "a rate that is applied constantly to the amount present at any instant"

Tags: continuity, exponential-function

(From Morris Kline's Calculus)

Talking about continuous compounded interest, he says:

"*The most important point about the above discussion is that continuous compounding of interest at the rate of 0.04 per year is an example of the phenomenon in which **a quantity changes continuously at a rate that is applied constantly to the amount present at any instant**.*"

The bolded part is very confusing to me. It sounds to me as if he's saying that at any instant during that year, the quantity grows at a rate of $\frac{0.04}{year}$, and I can't make sense out of that.

I understand $e$ defined as $\lim_{t \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{t})^t$. What I'm thinking is that if you broke down that $4\%$ into $4$ times $1\%$ compounded every 3 months, you wouldn't say at the second instance of $1\%$ return after 6 months that your fund is growing at a rate of $\frac{0.04}{year}$, or would you?

This is all very confusing...I'm really looking for intuition, whether geometric, physical or other. Thank you.

Comment: You're close: at a given instant, it increases at a rate of $0.04$ times the amount that is currently present, per year. So if you start with 1 unit, at the beginning you increase at $0.04$ per year. A month later, you have $e^{0.04/12}$, so you are increasing at $0.04 e^{0.04/12}$ per year--which is a bit more than you were getting at the start.

Comment: @Ian, but that's precisely what I don't understand. Why are we still growing at 0.04/year at every instant? Taking my example of 4% compounded as 1% every 3 months, you wouldn't say that after 3 months you have 1.01 and at that moment are growing at (0.04 * 1.01)/year, right?

Comment: After 3 months you have $1.01$; your next compounding will yield $(0.04 \cdot 1.01) \cdot \frac{1}{4}$, so that over the course of the next 3 months, you are growing at a rate of $0.04 \cdot 1.01$ *on average*. The "on average" part goes away with instantaneous compounding.

Comment: @Ian, when you say "...so that over the course of the next 3 months, you are growing at a rate of $0.04 \cdot 1.01$ *on average*", do you mean by "*on average*" $0.04 \cdot 1.01$ **per year**? Or is there no "per" anything? Sorry for being obtuse...I'm trying to compare for example with velocity in terms of average vs. instantaneous, but even average velocity would still be "per unit of time". Now it's almost like the continuous growth case makes more sense to me than the discrete case...

Comment: @Ian, Yes! I got it...finally. Oh, the joys of self-studying :P
Thanks for your help, you saved me from insanity :)